# hive queries take a long time

Tags: hive, hiveql

My hive queries take a long time. What can I do to mitigate against that?

What are some ways to optimize queries?

- I try to look at the partitions on the table and make sure I'm filtering the results based on the partition like date.

Here's my query

```
CREATE VIEW dwo_analysis.spark_experiment_unbounce_control_lookup_b AS
SELECT

a.visid,
a.date_time

FROM dwo_analysis.spark_experiment_unbounce_control_list a

LEFT JOIN dwo_analysis.spark_experiment_unbounce_aq_list aq ON aq.visid = a.visid
LEFT JOIN dwo_analysis.spark_experiment_unbounce_ap_list ap ON ap.visid = a.visid

WHERE ap.visid IS NULL
AND aq.visid IS NULL;
```

Comment: Writing a good SQL also helps; avoiding sub-queries and many joins. Btw, where is your query?

Comment: is visidid unique in aq and ap tables?

Comment: You don't use any partitions it looks like in this query, but you mentioned that in your write up.  What are your tables partitioned by?